# Different path requirement for php include vs inserting other assets. Why?

Tags: php, apache, server

I'm trying to understand why one code block works and another doesn't.

I recently began working in a dedicated server environment. All of my previous experience has been in a shared server environment.

**Works**

```
  <?php include('/home/benrud/public_html/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/divLayout/assets/includes/menu/menu.php'); ?>
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
<?php include('/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/divLayout/assets/includes/menu/menu.php'); ?>
```

**Error Received When Doesn't Work**

```
Warning: include(/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/divLayout/assets/includes/menu/menu.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/benrud/public_html/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/divLayout/index.php on line 27

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/divLayout/assets/includes/menu/menu.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/benrud/public_html/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/divLayout/index.php on line 27
```

Why is the `/home/benrud/public_html` required for a php include, but `<img src="/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/divLayout/assets/includes/menu/internships.jpg"/>` works for including an image in the same page?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: See [Mapping URLs to Filesystem Locations](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On HTML the default base url is current web server path which it is www or public_html

On PHP the base url is user path or root path of the server

On other words, visitors can't access /home/benrud/ they are only authorized to access public_html, but PHP can access most on server directories

Try to use ../ instead of / on the url

Answer (score 0):

`include` uses internal references, the server is accessing itself using its own file system. Whilst web pages use external references, they are telling the client's browser to access the server's web server.